# How to convert speech-to-text using node js in ibm watson

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

We are trying  speech-to-text using node js in ibm watson. We created node js application and speech to text server in ibm cloud. We are able to convert audio file to text using node js APIs(https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text)

Now we need while voice recording need convert speech to text .Can any one guide us what need do.

```
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('ibm-watson/speech-to-text/v1');
var fs = require('fs');
var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
  username: 'apikey',
  password: '{apikey}',
  url: 'https://{icp_cluster_host}{:port}/speech-to-text/api'
});
var params = {
  objectMode: true,
  content_type: 'audio/flac',
  model: 'en-US_BroadbandModel',
  keywords: ['colorado', 'tornado', 'tornadoes'],
  keywords_threshold: 0.5,
  max_alternatives: 3
};
// Create the stream.
var recognizeStream = speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket(params);
// Pipe in the audio.
fs.createReadStream('audio-file.flac').pipe(recognizeStream);
recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('error', function(event) { onEvent('Error:', event); });
recognizeStream.on('close', function(event) { onEvent('Close:', event); });
```

based on Node API we got Audio file convert into text.Now we expected Micro phone audio need convert into text.we don't get how to do that

expected image[image]

when hold on micro phone its should convert audio to text in text filed. Please guide us.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you have written code to share? There are code samples in the SDK repo on GitHub to adapt

Comment: @data_henrik thanks for reply.yes we will update code please help

Comment: I would recommend to check https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/tree/master/examples/ and https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/ It has examples for what you are looking for